# error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol cvSmooth referenced in function "void __cdecl example2_4(struct _IplImage *)"

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, opencv, lnk2019, unresolved-external

I hope that anyone familiar with openCV and image processing will help me soon.
I'm absolutely new to openCV and VC++ and this is the third time this week, I've encountered the error LNK2019.
I know that this error means that the .lib file containing the specified function has not been linked to the project and it's appropriate header file has not been included at top of the code.
But this time based on [this web page](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/imgproc.html) I glean that cvSmooth is the function included in `opencv_imgproc243d.lib` so I have added this .lib as the `Additional Dependencies` and have written the line

```
#include "opencv2\imgproc\imgproc.hpp"
```

at top of my code but the error

```
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol cvSmooth referenced in function "void __cdecl example2_4(struct _IplImage *)"
```

does not change and remains the same.
I've been really confused????
Any help would be appreciated and if it's needed, tell me to add the code as an edited section to my question,please.
Is it wrong and `cvSmooth` belongs to another .lib file?

---

**Edited section of my question based on h3now's suggestion**

**My code is as follows:**

```
#include "stdafx.h"  
#include "opencv\cv.h"  
#include "opencv\highgui.h"  
#include "opencv2\core\core.hpp"  
#include "opencv2\imgproc\imgproc.hpp"  

void example2_4( IplImage* image )  
{
   // Create some windows to show the input  
   // and output images in.  
   //  
   cvNamedWindow( "Example4-in",CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );  
   cvNamedWindow( "Example4-out",CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );  
   // Create a window to show our input image  
   //  
   cvShowImage( "Example4-in", image );  
   // Create an image to hold the smoothed output  
   //  
   IplImage* out = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(image),IPL_DEPTH_8U,3);  
   // Do the smoothing  
   //  
   // Do the smoothing  
   //  
   cvSmooth( image, out, CV_GAUSSIAN, 3, 3 );  
   // Show the smoothed image in the output window  
   //  
   cvShowImage( "Example4-out", out );  
   // Be tidy  
   //  
   cvReleaseImage( &out );  
   // Wait for the user to hit a key, then clean up the windows  
   //
   cvWaitKey( 0 );
   cvDestroyWindow( "Example4-in" );  
   cvDestroyWindow( "Example4-out" );  
}  




int main(int argc,  char* argv[])  
{  
    IplImage* img = cvLoadImage(argv[1]);
    example2_4( img );
    cvReleaseImage( &img );  
    system("pause");  
    return 0;  
}
```

**For example when I right-click on the function `cvCreateImage` and and choose `Go To Definition` a file named core_c.h gets opened. So understand that this function's prototype is included in core_c.h.**
**So for this reason we understand that we should write `#include "opencv2\core\core.hpp"` or `#include "opencv2\core\core_c.h"`(I think using any of the two codes makes no difference) at the top of our code and link `opency_core243d.lib` to the project to use the function `cvCreateImage`**
**But when I right-click on `cvSmooth` and choose `Go To Definition`, nothing happens**
**Does the solution that @h3now suggested work for all of the functions?**
**Because when I also right-click on cvShowImage, nothing happens.**

Comment: Sometimes this libs include some others. Just make sure you are not missing the core lib or some other.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same error. I'm using opencv 2.2 instead of 2.4.3, nevertheless the solution should be equivalent.

A good way to discover wich file you need to include is (in visual studio) right-clicking the function name in the code and selecting "Go to Definition". By doing this I realized that I should include the `imgproc_c.h` header file, instead of the `imgproc.hpp`.

Comment: thanks for your attention but look at the `Edited section of my question based on h3now's suggestion` to see the problem that I really have.